# What is the difference between Types and Dictionaries in terms of the underlying map structures and use-cases?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Coming from JavaScript to C#, and without a computer science background, I've noticed similarities between c# types (classes) and Dictionary. And then both of these can be serialized to JSON, which is familiar to me working with JavaScript.

What is the difference between `Dictionary<string, <T, <etc>>>` (which is effectively `Dictionary<string, object>`) and creating encapsulated structures with types.

I'm referring to data structures and not class-based programming. An example use case is that I was creating a chart.js object in C#. I could either have created a simple type system or I could build up a data structure using `Dictionary<string, object>` (which is what I did).

In hindsight I would say that building nested Dictionarys/Lists/etc was quicker than using types, but that building a class structure would be more readable and maintainable.

I mean, a type must basically be a map as is a Dictionary. What is the difference behind the scenes between maps that represent types and maps that represent Dictionaries.

For example:

```
class A {
   List<B> this.someList;
}

class B {
   string this.name;
}
```

You effectively create objects like:

```
A obj = [<instance of B>, <instance of B>, etc]
```

Which can easily be serialized to JSON

Comment: What makes you think that `Type` is even remotely equivalent to a dictionary?  One is a core fundamental of the CLR and contains large amounts of metadata and the other is a collection.

Comment: @DavidL In JavaScript, an object is a dictionary, just like in .NET when you cast an `ExpandoObject` to `IDictionary<String, Object>`. I think by "Types" he means classes, not instances of `System.Type`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I understand what you are saying, but your second example isn't equatable to type vs dictionary.  ExpandoObject simply implements `IDictionary<,,>` whereas a Type is far more fundamental than a collection.  That said I may be completely misunderstanding the question.

Comment: *"a type must basically be a map as is a Dictionary"* -- profoundly wrong. C# class members are not looked up by name at runtime. *"I would say that building nested Dictionarys/Lists/etc was quicker than using types, but that building a class structure would be more readable and maintainable"* -- yes! That is an excellent one-sentence summary of the distinction between the two kinds of typesystems.

Comment: I was refering to classes as types. is that incorrect? I.e. `class A` would be a template for creating items of `type A`. sorry if this is incorrect

Comment: @DavidL He's assuming that C# objects must be implemented that way, because that's the only mental model he has for an object oriented typesystem. If he'd learned C first, as I did, he would have encountered the JS type system at some point and been like [DUDE WHOA THAT'S LIKE... WHOA](http://www.reactiongifs.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/mind_blown.gif), like I did.

Comment: @EdPlunkett ahh, I see, thanks Ed. Therein lies the rub...they simply aren't equatable.

Comment: Types can have all kinds of other stuff like methods, events, indexers, etc. With a dictionary you are stuck to just key-value pairs (which is sort of equivalent to properties and fields).

Comment: @ZachSmith "Template" is the wrong way to think about it. JS's prototype-based inheritance is pretty cool, but it's very, very unlike the way .NET classes work. [Members, or references to members, are laid out sequentially in a block of memory](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/03/15/virtual-method-dispatch-and-object-layout-changes-in-clr-40/), and referenced at runtime by byte offset. The compiler worries about what names refer to what offsets and generates code appropriately. What if a DLL you're linking to gets recompiled, with changes to the layout of its classes? I haven't a clue!

Comment: @ZachSmith The confusion about the word "Type" is that in the CLR (C#, VB.NET, etc.), there's a class called [`System.Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) which describes a CLR data type (a class, or value types like `int` etc.). You can get an appropriate instance of `System.Type` from an object, e.g. `obj.GetType()`, and do extremely clunky and inconvenient stuff that sort of resembles a subset of what you can do with a JS object. But I think you were referring to lowercase "type", just datatypes, not the `System.Type` class itself.

Comment: Although a class object in C# looks a lot like a Javascript object, the way that they are implemented is very different.

In Javascript when you write thing.fieldA the runtime system does a lookup of the string "fieldA" to find the associated value.  This is similar to a C# Dictionary.

In C# when you write thing.fieldA there is no lookup.  It has computed the location of fieldA in the class during compile and during runtime it's a simple calculation to get the offset from the beginning of the object.  As a result a C# class is vastly faster

Comment: @RayFischer. Would it be fair to say that the structure of data in a in a javascript object vs a C# class is similar?

Comment: Not in the slightest.  There is no analog to a C# class in Javascript.  The fields of a C# class are laid out in memory and the compiler determines the offset from the beginning of the object for each field, and then generates instructions which directly access those fields.  Javascript does a table lookup to find the location of object members, similar to a C# Dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One big difference between the C# and javascript is that a variable in js can hold any value, while C# is strongly typed: you cannot store a string in an `int` variable.

In the javascript world, dictionaries and objects are fairly similar (by design). In the C# world they are very different! Some differences based on usage:

**Dictionary**:

- it is a list of key-value pairs
- all keys have the same strong type (string, int, DateTime, .. ), defined at the declaration of the dictionary.
- all values have the same strong type, also declared. This may be different from the type of the key.
- keys must be unique, which is checked at runtime
- value lookup (by key) is done at runtime
- you can add any key-value pair at runtime (as long as the key is unique)
- no methods can be added (unless the type of the value is some `Func<>` or `Action<>` type, and then all values are methods)

**Class** (Type):

- properties are strongly typed. Two properties may use different types.
- names of properties are checked at *compile* time, and the types of the values assigned
- available property names are defined in the class definition, along with their types. It it not possible (or wanted) to add new properties at runtime (let's ignore `dynamic`).
- methods can be added at class definition and not later (ignoring extension methods - which still can only be added at compile time)
- properties don't just store values, they can contain code as well - for instance to calculate it's value

So if you want to define a lookup, you may use a Dictionary. When you want to store address data, define and use an Address class.